# How to solve Newton's Gravity equations when both bodies are moving

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I am struggling to numerically solve Newton's equation for gravity using scipy.integrate.solve_ivp. I can get the coding working when one of the bodies is assumed stationary. However as shown in the picture when I use the code below where I am trying to account for the force of the sun on Jupiter and that of Jupiter on the sun, the suns orbit is not correct. It doesn't seem to wobble but instead just heads off away from the COM.

```
G = 6.67408e-11
msun = 1988500e24
m_jupiter = 1898.13e24

x_pos_j = 2.939022030646856E+00*au
y_pos_j = -4.169544536356319E+00*au
z_pos_j = -4.843813063988785E-02*au

x_vel_j = 6.083727195546033E-03*v_factor
y_vel_j = 4.708328571996785E-03*v_factor
z_vel_j = -1.556609498459863E-04*v_factor

def f_grav(t, y):
    x1, x2, x3, v1, v2, v3 = y
    # x1_star, x2_star, x3_star = x_other
    dydt = [v1,
            v2,
            v3,
            -(x1-x1_star)*G*m/((x1-x1_star)**2+(x2-x2_star)**2+(x3-x3_star)**2)**(3/2),
            -(x2-x2_star)*G*m/((x1-x1_star)**2+(x2-x2_star)**2+(x3-x3_star)**2)**(3/2),
            -(x3-x3_star)*G*m/((x1-x1_star)**2+(x2-x2_star)**2+(x3-x3_star)**2)**(3/2)]
    return dydt

x_jupiter = np.array([x_pos_j, y_pos_j, z_pos_j])
x_sun = np.array([0, 0, 0])
v_sun = np.array([0, 0, 0])

tStart = 0e0
t_End = 20*year
dt = t_End/3000
# minstep = dt/100
domain = (tStart, dt)
temp_end = dt

x1_star, x2_star, x3_star = [0, 0, 0]
init_j = [x_pos_j, y_pos_j, z_pos_j, x_vel_j, y_vel_j, z_vel_j]
init_sun = [20, -20, 20, 15, -15, 0]

while tStart < t_End:
    
    m=msun
    ans_j = solve_ivp(fun=f_grav, t_span=domain, y0=init_j)
    x1_star, x2_star, x3_star = ans_j['y'][0:3, -1]
    v1_star, v2_star, v3_star = ans_j['y'][3:6, -1]
    x_jupiter = np.vstack((x_jupiter, (ans_j['y'][0:3, -1])))
    init_j = [x1_star, x2_star, x3_star, v1_star, v2_star, v3_star]
    # print(init_j[0:3])
    
    m=m_jupiter
    ans_sun = solve_ivp(fun=f_grav, t_span=domain, y0=init_sun)
    x1_star, x2_star, x3_star = ans_sun['y'][0:3, -1]
    v1_star, v2_star, v3_star = ans_sun['y'][3:6, -1]
    
    v_sun = np.vstack((v_sun, (ans_sun['y'][3:6, -1])))
    x_sun = np.vstack((x_sun, (ans_sun['y'][0:3, -1])))
    init_sun = [x1_star, x2_star, x3_star, v1_star, v2_star, v3_star]
    
    tStart += dt
    temp_end = tStart + dt
    domain = (tStart,temp_end)

plt.plot(x_jupiter[:,0], x_jupiter[:,1])

plt.plot(x_sun[:,0], x_sun[:,1])

plt.show()
```

In the code at any given moment to solve the equation I assume that the other star is stationary but only for dt, which I don't think should effect the results. Is this why my plots are wrong and if so how can I better solve the equation when both bodies are moving. The orbit of Jupiter (blue on right image) looks more less correct but not that of the sun (on both images and is orange).

[image]

Comment: Is it the the body system problem that you want to solve? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem

Comment: Kind of, I am trying to do just two bodies to start off with but I want to have an n body system where all the particles masses effect each others in the end.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65346350/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133439/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  Please pick one site where you'd like your question to appear.

Comment: apologies, didn't think it was a right fit for compsci but forgot to delete it

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53813499/python-euler-method-implementation-in-two-body-problem-not-working, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65084648/python-implementation-of-n-body-problem for other implementations of systems with multiple planets